# How to exclude directory from getting bundled by Webpack?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

**Expected:**

When I build with webpack, all my JS files get bundled except for the files in the ./src/Portfolio directory as per my Webpack.config.js settings.

**Actual:**

Webpack bundles all the files including the ones in the directory despite the settings and other variations i have provided within webpack.config.js.

**Code:**

Webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, './src/Portfolio/')
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

**Output:**

[image]

> How can i successfully exclude the ./src/Portfolio directory and its
>   contents?

Comment: can you try `path.resolve(__dirname, './src/Portfolio/*')` ?

Comment: The portfolio directory still gets included, the output did not change. I ran with npx webpack

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Depending on what your folder structure looks like it appears you aren't providing it the right directory location to exclude.  I would think something like this should work, but if not please share your folder structure.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: [
          './src/Portfolio/'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

Comment: Strange it worked! thanks dude!, also we are big fan of yours Chris, watching for years feel free to drop by and join our Youtube developers community here  https://discord.gg/gE5kZx you'd be VIP straight away cheers

Comment: That is awesome :) thank you!  I will look to join.  I've been terribly busy lately but it's starting to even out.

Comment: how to exclude, the multiple folder in exclude array, I have used but not working for me. `exclude: [
    /node_modules/,
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'images/' + project.appName)
  ]`

Comment: @Anupam Maurya, I think that you have to use RegEx instead of an array of strings. This is working exclude: [/node_modules/, /images/, /content/]

Answer (score 11):

I know the op is using javascript, fyi a similar problem can occur using typescript with webpack.

In this case excluded directories can be added to `tsconfig.json` instead of `webpack.config.js`,

```js
//tsconfig.json

{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
    },
    "exclude": [
        "./src/Portfolio/",
    ]
}
```