# Laravel Mix exclude a specific directory

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-mix

How can you tell laravel mix / npm to exclude searching a specific directory (and it's subdirectories) when you run "npm run prod"?  I'm assuming its searching for directories with package.json or bower.json (I ran an strace and found it recursing the offending directory searching for these files)

I have a symlink in my public directory that contains thousands of subdirectories and files.  This causes 'npm run prod' to take 20 minutes to finish running (searching through the thousands of subdirectories).

Is there a way to explicitly skip this directory from being recursed?

Comment: I believe you need an exclude block but I can't the exact syntax. The closest I got was for [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52059366/how-to-exclude-directory-from-getting-bundled-by-webpack) but it's for an older version.