# Ignore specific folder and file type from render

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I use `vue-cli` with `webpack` (webpack version 4.44.2) and i need to ignore `.ogg` files only from `sounds` directory, I've tried to reproduce [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52059366/how-to-exclude-directory-from-getting-bundled-by-webpack) but it did not work for me, i don't know why, seems like webpack just ignore the lines:

vue.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');

let webpackConfig = {
    // my other code
    configureWebpack: {
          module: {
              rules: [
                  {
                      test: /\.ogg$/,
                      exclude: [ path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'sounds') ]
                  }
              ]
         },
    }
};
```

```
My file structure:

- public
  - sounds
    - sound1.ogg
    - sound2.ogg
- vue.config.js
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Does it break the build or what behavior do you get when there's no exclusion?  How are you using the files in your app?

Comment: Nothing changes, no crashes when i exclude the files or not. I use `.ogg` files with `new Howler({ src: [".ogg file src"] })`. It doesn't break the build, I think webpack somewhy ignore the rule.

Comment: The path seems like it matches the one you linked.  But maybe try `exclude: [ './src/public/sounds' ]` anyway

Comment: Webpack throw an error which says I must to provide full path so I create full path to the directory with `path.join`