# Webpack: use data from parent directory without copying

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a project folder structured like this:

```
project-name/   
  data/
   data.csv
  dist/
   index.js
  src/
   index.js
```

And want a remote directory like this:

```
project-name/   
  data/
   data.csv
  dist/
   index.js
    > `doSomething("../data/data.csv")`
```

How do I make this work in both webpack-dev-server and in the production path? If I use copywebpack plugin, then the data goes inside the dist/, which I don't want. But if I use a relative directory without copying the data, then the build fails.

Comment: *different iterations of the same page* can you detail this?

Comment: I've removed that and simplified the question (I hope)

Comment: By "FTP path" I imagine you mean "remote folder structure" or somesuch. A path is a single address.

Comment: Correct, edited.

Comment: What version of webpack are you using? And could you share your current setup of webpack?

Comment: Is this a node project? if so then you can use fs to read the csv without importing it

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you should use Webpack [`csv-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-loader) in your Webpack configuration file like below:

```js
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.csv$/,
      loader: 'csv-loader',
      options: {
      dynamicTyping: true,
        header: true,
        skipEmptyLines: true,
      },
    },
  ],
},
```

And then use it inside your code like below:

```js
import csvPath from './project-name/data/foo.csv'
```

Comment: I tried this, but it resulted in an enormous bundle.js file

Comment: @Kyouma, I read your question, this part was so important to me `without copying the data`, because you don't want to have it in your `dist` folder, so you should have it inside your bundle, correct? to prevent users to download it directly. That's the inevitable solution, if the bundle is so huge, ok, then use bundle splitting. and split the huge part inside a chunk bundle file. that could be a part to complete your solution.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to access it through the parent directory when in build, not to be included within the folder at all.

Comment: @Kyouma, but this sentence: `but I want to access it through the parent directory when in build` means you need `webpack-copy-plugin`, why you don't want to use it? I remember you wrote you don't want to use copying and you don't want users have directly access to it and have download ability. correct?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use an alias?

webpack.config.js:

```
  const path = require("path");

  module.exports = {
  ...

    resolve: {
      alias: {
        Data: path.resolve(__dirname, "./project-name/data/"),
      },
    },
  }
```

src/index.js:

```
  import data from "Data/data.csv"
```

Comment: Thanks, but importing it retains the original problem - it puts the data within the dist folder as a part of the overall bundle. And I don't think I can reference the alias in non-import statements.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried excluding it in the test? Something like this:

```
   {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          use: ["babel-loader or whatever loader you use"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.csv$/,
          exclude: ["./data/"],
        },
      ],
    },
    output: {
      filename: "index.js",
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    },
   },
```

There is a similar question on how to not bundle files in webpack [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52059366/how-to-exclude-directory-from-getting-bundled-by-webpack/52060231)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [context](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/#context) param.

```
    new CopyWebpackPlugin(
    [{
        context: './source/',
        from: '**/*.html',
        to: './public',
        force: true
    }], {
        copyUnmodified: true
    }
)
```